# Haskell Map: Transform key and catch errors

Tags: dictionary, haskell, error-handling

I struggle to find a solution (other than using `Data.Map.fromList` and `toList`) for the following problem:

Transform the key with a function that returns an `Either String k` where as usual errors are expressed as `Left`, and the whole transformation fails if a single key-transformation fails.

```
import Data.Map.Strict

mapEitherKey :: (k -> Either String k') -> Map k a -> Either String (Map k' a)
```

For the right-hand side `v` of `Map k v` it is easily done with `mapM`, because
`Map k` is an instance of `Monad`.

But none of the [mapping functions](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.3.1/docs/Data-Map-Strict.html#g:19) offers anything functorial in the key. (I wonder whether there's a deeper reason why `Map` is not an instance of `Bifunctor`, for instance. I do see that it's not trivial because key collisions need to be taken into account.)

Any insights would be appreciated.

Comment: It can't be a bifunctor because of the `Ord` constraint on keys. Also, applying an arbitrary function on keys can break the tree invariant (the function could be non-monotonic, or non-injective), so one would need to construct a new tree from scratch, effectively using something like `fromList/toList`.

Comment: The library does offer `mapKeys :: Ord k2 => (k1 -> k2) -> Map k1 a -> Map k2 a` for some functioriality on keys. It is O(n*log n) instead of O(n) because the tree needs to be rebuilt. If you have a monotonic function, you can use `mapKeysMonotonic :: (k1 -> k2) -> Map k1 a -> Map k2 a` which runs in O(n) -- be careful not to break the invariant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to second what @chi said; unless you know that the order is preserved, you'll have to reinsert the key each time. Which means that `toList` and then reinserting with `fromList` should be the best you can get asymptotically.

However, since you asked for a way to do it without those functions, I'd like to suggest using [`foldMapWithKey`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.3.1/docs/Data-Map-Strict.html#v:foldMapWithKey).

```
import Data.Monoid (Ap(..))
import qualified Data.Map as M


mapEitherKey :: (Ord k, Ord k') => (k -> Either String k') -> Map k a -> Either String (Map k' a)
mapEitherKey f = getAp . M.foldMapWithKey (\k v -> Ap (flip M.singleton v <$> f k))
```

The idea for this is to lift the reconstruction of the map with key `k'` (which we do by unioning together a bunch of singletons) into the `Either String` Applicative, which will short circuit if it encounters a `Left`.

I wrote it kind of quick and dirty, but you can refactor it to be more readable. It should be asymptotically ideal, but there might be more performant approaches.

Note that you need the `Ord` constraints on `k` and `k'`.

Example usage:

```
Prelude> f k = if k > 10 then Left "bad number" else Right $ show k
Prelude> mapEitherKey f (M.fromList [(0,0),(1,1),(2,2)])
Right (fromList [("0",0),("1",1),("2",2)])
Prelude> mapEitherKey f (M.fromList [(0,0),(1,1),(2,2),(11,11)])
Left "bad number"
```